# How to remove a file from both chunks and files in GridFS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs, gridfs-stream

**Mongoose**

```
var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var GridFS = Grid(mongoose.connection.db, mongoose.mongo);
GridFS.collection('backupdata').remove({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.file_id)}, function (err) {
    console.log("deleted");
});
```

Here I created a collection("dbmanager") for saving files. When I try to remove file from dbmanager collection, the document will remove from "dbmanager.files". But documents still showing in "dbmanager.chunks". I need to remove that documents from "dbmanager.files" and "dbmanager.chunks".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did this recently using [gridfs-stream](https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream)

Then the gfs driver does it for you:

```
gfs.remove(options, function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log('success');
});
```

or

```
gfs.remove({ _id: fileId });
```

Comment: It's in their github code here:

https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream/blob/c394e050d066a5c81c6dcdddad186b08a93d5f1f/lib/index.js#L87

Comment: it no longer works, I get DeprecationWarning: collection.remove is deprecated. Use deleteOne, deleteMany, or bulkWrite instead.